# Changing record ownership based on URL click

Tags: apex

I am trying to achieve change-of-ownership(update operation) once a SF user clicks on the provided URL.

**Use-case:** Our customers works in two applications (Salesforce and Sharepoint). We have an integration such that, when we create a custom object's record within our SF, it would trigger a web service call out and creates a record within the Sharepoint app. Here, within the Sharepoint app, the customer will be provided with a URL to access the SF record.

**Current solution**: We are sending the standard URL as below:

```
System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + recId
```

This works great. Customer can click and it would open the SF record in a new tab.

**Question:** Now that, I am trying to update the ownership based on whoever clicks the URL, is there a way? I heard about the URL hacking, but that ultimately opens the SF record in the **Edit** mode, but does not update the record's ownership. Any thoughts/resources would be really appreciated.

Comment: Without code? Not really. If you wanted to, though, a simple Visualforce page or Lightning Component could achieve this goal.

Comment: The URL sits in another application, so is it still possible to implement VF page or Lightning component?

Comment: As long as you can link to Salesforce, it should be possible. For example, the URL might look like `mydomain.my.salesforce.com/apex/changeOwner?id={recId}`

Comment: Great, this looks simple than I thought. I will try to do it and will get back to you.

Comment: @sfdcfox I got it worked. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as user is authorised to salesforce, one of the ideas could be to create a lightning component (or visualforce page), which will take a record id as parameter and update owner and or any other fields as page is being loaded, and as soon as it is completed -- navigate to a record id.

In case of no-code solutions -- it would be possible to make a flow, which will do the same, based on a record id. That might require for user to do an extra click in order to finish a flow (or on a link in the last flow screen).

Comment: I have implemented a VF page with basic `action` to call the controller's method where I took care of the update/redirect flow.